# Convert a macro argument into a string constant and take into account commas

Tags: c++, c, macros

Say I have a C macro-defined product version like this:

```
#define FOO_VERSION 1,0,0,1
```

And I want to print it at run-time:

```
#define STRING_VALUE(x) #x

int main()
{
    std::cout << STRING_VALUE(FOO_VERSION) << std::endl;
}
```

This will output a string "FOO_VERSION", not "1,0,0,1". The macro
argument 'FOO_VERSION' is not replaced. So I try it again like
this:

```
#define STRING_VALUE(x) STRING_VALUE__(x)
#define STRING_VALUE__(x) #x

int main()
{
    std::cout << STRING_VALUE(FOO_VERSION) << std::endl;
}
```

It works, in Visual C++ 2013.

This is a cross-platform application although there are only five
lines of code. When I use clang to compile the code, a compile-
time error appears: "too many arguments provided to function-like
macro invocation". I guess the reason is the comma defined in
'FOO_VERSION'. So the third version:

```
#define STRING_VALUE(x) STRING_VALUE__(x)
#define STRING_VALUE__(a, b, c, d) #a "," #b "," #c "," #d

int main()
{
    std::cout << STRING_VALUE(FOO_VERSION) << std::endl;
}
```

This code works in clang, but Visual C++ will output a warning:
"not enough actual parameters for macro 'STRING_VALUE__'" at
compile-time, of course the run-time output is not right.

My question: is this pre-processor behavior defined ? Can I have a
universal version of STRING_VALUE macro ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can treat the argument as a single variadic macro:

```
#define FOO_VERSION 1,0,0,1

#define STRING_VALUE(...) STRING_VALUE__(__VA_ARGS__)
#define STRING_VALUE__(...) #__VA_ARGS__
```

This seems to work with gcc and Visual C++.

Comment: Why didn't I think of that ?